# RoR + CanCan: Check nested condition in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have User and Post models. User has many posts and Post belongs to User. I want allow admin to delete user only if he hasn't posts, so now I have in my ability.rb:

```
can :destroy, User do |u|
    u.posts.empty?
end
```

But can I write this in one line (something like `can :destroy, User, :posts => empty?`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one-line block

```
can(:destroy, User) { |u| u.posts.empty? }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
can :destroy, User {|u| u.posts.empty? }
```